# How to generate a random number 2^128

Tags: java

how to generate a random number **2^128** using standard data types?

How to work with such large numbers in **java**?

Comment: What do you want to do with that number and why does it need to be 128 bits long?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-java.util.Random-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BigInteger` Constructs a randomly generated BigInteger, uniformly distributed over the range 0 to (2numBits - 1), inclusive.

> The uniformity of the distribution assumes that a fair source of
>   random bits is provided in rnd. Note that this constructor always
>   constructs a non-negative BigInteger.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class BigRandom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger result = getRandomBigInteger();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static BigInteger getRandomBigInteger() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger(128, rand); // (2^128-1) maximum value

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The largest Java primitive data type `long` is too small (64bit), therefore we have to use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
byte[] data = new byte[16]; // 16 * 8 = 128 bit
rnd.nextBytes(data);
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, data); // interpret the data as positive number
```

Comment: Because 2^128 is 128 bits.

Comment: @JoseMartinez I don't think you understand how bits work, either. 2^n is literally the definition for *n* bits, so 2^128 is exactly 128 bits.

Comment: Yes, exactly. *n* bits can store 2^n (2 raised to the power of *n*) bits of information. Therefore you need exactly 128 bits for the number 2^128 (2 raised to the power of 128).

Comment: Wolframalpha doesn't show you bits, it shows you decimal digits.

Comment: What? Why would I multiply decimal digits by 8? Computers store data in binary, not in decimal. Storing one decimal digit in one byte is a waste of bits. A single byte can store 256 different values. Thats exactly 2^8. 8 bits for 2^8 values. 128 bits for 2^128 values.

Comment: @JJJ got it.  doing simple math way too early int he AM.  thanks!